# Enabling MT_SERVICE results in Internal Server error

Tags: weblate

Regardless of which **MT_SERVICES** I try to enable in settings.py, after restating Apache, I get an Internal Server error when accessing the site.
I tried to enable one or two services, but did always get the same problem.

I tried enabling different services. Nothing worked. When I remove the **MT_SERVICES**, everything is back to normal.

```
MT_SERVICES = (
    'weblate.machinery.deepl.DeepLTranslation',
    'weblate.machinery.saptranslationhub.SAPTranslationHub',
)
MT_DEEPL_KEY = xxxxxx

MT_SAP_BASE_URL = xxxxxx
MT_SAP_SANDBOX_APIKEY
MT_SAP_USERNAME = xxxxxx
MT_SAP_PASSWORD = xxxxxx
MT_SAP_USE_MT = True
```

**Result:**
Error: Internal Server Error

Comment: Please check server logs for actual error message or enable debug mode (by setting `DEBUG = True` in `settings.py`) to see it in the browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michal. I did both, but there is nothing specific to MT in the weblate log, nore is there any more explicit message in the browser when I set "DEBUG = True"..

Comment: But in the apache log there is a message about the MT_SERVICE. And the solution is rather simple. I forgot to put "" around the key for the service...

Comment: Sorry to have bothered you with this. Again, thanks for the quick reply!